# How to call a class inside an object that's inside the render function of a component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native

I'm not sure how to describe what I'm trying to do with words so please take a look at the following code:

This is what causing me issues: **this.fetchMessages()**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PushNotificationIOS, FlatList, TextInput, ActivityIndicator, ListView, Text, View, Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import ConversationsItem from './ConversationsItem';
import { conversationFetch } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Divider } from 'react-native-elements'
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

class Conversations extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.conversationFetch()
  }

  fetchMessages() {
    this.props.conversationFetch()
  }

  render() {

    PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        PushNotification.getApplicationIconBadgeNumber((response) => {
            PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(response + 1)
        })

        console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification )
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);

        this.fetchMessages()

      }
    });

    if (!this.props.email) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    console.log(this.props.conversations)

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state)
  const { conversations } = state.conversation;
  const { email } = state.conversation;

  return { conversations, email };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { conversationFetch })(Conversations);
```

When I call this.fetchMessages() inside PushNotification.configure({}), I get the following error message:

> this.fetchMessages is not a function

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is possible but if so I'd really like to know how to make this work.

I tried adding .bind(this) and other ways around but got same error anyways.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Did you try the binding in the constructor?

Comment: @Dez I did but could you give an exemple of the exact syntax just to make sure?

Comment: @Hugo Just convert `onNotification: function(notification) {` to `onNotification: (notification) =>  {`

Comment: @Prakashsharma This works! I don't understand why tho could you explain what's the difference between the two syntax? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hugo Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions declared with `function` keyword has their own `this`, so `this` inside `onNotification` function does not refer to the class.

Therefore use arrow function syntax, which will lexically resolve `this` and value of `this` inside will refer to class itself. So convert

```
onNotification: function(notification) {
```

to

```
onNotification: (notification) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have in fact tried binding the `fetchMessages` function in the constructor? Like such:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.fetchMessages = this.fetchMessages.bind(this);
}
```

You can also use an arrow function to bind your method to the class without calling the constructor like such:

```
() => this.fetchMessages()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I followed Prakash's comment tho and it solved my problem.